cannot manage CUPS printers over http://
I have a CUPS server on my local network. I can connect to the CUPS web interface:
http://10.1.1.128:631/

but when I want to log in as admin, or manage printers, I get this message:

which after few seconds redirects to:

it does not allow me to use plain http:// even though I am connecting on my local network
http://10.1.1.128:631/admin/

I tried from Firefox and Chrome, and get same error.
How can I disable this idiocy?

Modern CUPS has a default setting of DefaultEncryption Required, which specifies that all authenticated requests must happen over an encrypted connection. In general, this is a sensible requirement, because without encryption, HTTP Basic Authentication will send the password unencrypted over the network.
To change that requirement, first stop CUPS, otherwise it will just overwrite any changes you make. For example, on distributions using systemd:
systemctl stop cups

Then edit /etc/cups/cupsd.conf. The DefaultEncryption is a top-level directive, so if it is already present, it should be outside any <Policy>, <Limit> or <Location> blocks. Add the directive before any of those blocks if it does not exist, and according to your preference, set it to:
DefaultEncryption IfRequested

if you still want to have the option to use encrypted connections, or
DefaultEncryption Never

if you are fine with no encryption at all (i.e. you are sure your network is secure enough for your purposes).
Then restart CUPS, with e.g.
systemctl start cups

